# "No numeric types to aggregate" while using Pandas expanding()

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

In Pandas 1.1.4, I am receiving a DataError: No numeric types to aggregate when using an ExpandingGroupby.

Example dataset:

```
tmp = pd.DataFrame({'col1':['a','b','b','c','d','d'], 'col2': ['red','red','green','green','red','blue']})

print(tmp)

col1    col2
a       red
b       red
b       green
c       green
d       red
d       blue
```

This works:

```
tmp.groupby('col1').agg(lambda x: ','.join(x))
```

And this works:

```
tmp.groupby('col1').expanding().agg('count')
```

But this returns an error:

```
tmp.groupby('col1').expanding().agg(lambda x: ','.join(x))
```

DataError: No numeric types to aggregate

There is no conceptual reason this shouldn't work, and there are several references online to people using custom functions within an ExpandingGroupby.

There is obviously no reason that this should need to be a numeric, especially given that the count works with the non-numeric column.  What is happening here?  If this can't be done natively for whatever reason, how can I do it manually?

Comment: The result should be numeric not the source (your column). This is the same for `rolling`. `count` returns numeric values so it's right.

Comment: @Corralien Doesn't the data in the frame need to be numeric in order to apply the custom function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `accumulate` from `itertools` module:

```
from itertools import accumulate

concat = lambda *args: ','.join(args)
expand = lambda x: list(accumulate(x, func=concat))

df['col3'] = df.groupby('col1')['col2'].transform(expand)
print(df)

# Output
  col1   col2       col3
0    a    red        red
1    b    red        red
2    b  green  red,green
3    c  green      green
4    d    red        red
5    d   blue   red,blue
```

**Update**

One line version:

```
df['col3'] = df.groupby('col1')['col2'].transform(lambda x: list(accumulate(x, func=lambda *args: ','.join(args))))
```

Comment: Just for fun, I converted my answer to a one line version :)

Comment: Do you know how this would be modified to include everything _except_ the current row?

Comment: So for the first element of the group, the value should be an empty string?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly right.  It should be a list of all _previous_ values.

Comment: The simple way is to use `expand = lambda x: [''] + list(accumulate(x, func=concat))[:-1]`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to join the previous rows values to the next inside the group, perhaps you could use `cumsum` and add strings as you go:

```
tmp['expading_join'] = tmp.groupby('col1')['col2'].apply(lambda x: (x + ',').cumsum()).str.rstrip(',')
```

Output:

```
  col1   col2 expading_join
0    a    red           red
1    b    red           red
2    b  green     red,green
3    c  green         green
4    d    red           red
5    d   blue      red,blue
```

Answer (score 1):

A third option I have found:

```
tmp['col3'] = tmp.groupby('col1')['col2'].transform(lambda x: [';'.join(x[:i+1]) for i in range(len(x))])
```

Putting this out there in case it is useful to anyone; however, both the options by @enke and @Corralien are superior.

Tested on a large dataset, the times were:

```
accumulate: 0:13
apply: 0:25
for loop:  2:28
```

Since the accumulate option was faster and more intuitive, I am marking that as the accepted answer, although the other is very nice for being a one liner with no imports.

Comment: I'm agree. the answer of @enke is great too but need to come back to remove the last `','`. You can transform my answer to a one liner but there is a lack of comprehension :)